# How to find the value of $4\int \frac{1}{y(3y+2)}dy$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve:

$4\int \frac{1}{y(3y+2)}dy$

And I got up to:

$-4\int \frac{1}{v^{2}+1}dv$ However, I used symbolab to help me get to this stage. Although, it mentions here:
[image]

Is there a proof for common integral in the image?

I though it would have made sense to have $\int \frac{1}{v^{2}+1}= tan^{-1}(v)$, why is this not the case? ***I know why this does not work now***

Whilst practicing from the given hint, I've come this far:

$\frac{-v^{2}-1}{-v^{2}+1}-\frac{1}{-v^{2}+1} = \frac{v^{2}+2}{-v^2+1}$ am I on the right track?

although i'm thinking that I could do:

$4\int\frac{2}{v+1}-\frac{1}{v-1} dv?$ This gets me: $4[2 \ln|v+1| - \ln|v-1|]$ Although, I'm not sure how to derive the fraction $\frac{1}{2}$.

The equation on top is only part of an equation.

The full equation is:

$$\int \frac{3y-4}{y(3y+2)}dy$$

So I split it into:

$\int \frac{3y}{y(3y+2)}dy$ - $4\int \frac{1}{y(3y+2)}dy$ As this was easier.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y(3y+2)} & = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{y(3y+2)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{(3y + 2) - 3y}{y(3y+2)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\times\left(\frac{1}{y} - \frac{3}{3y+2}\right)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you check my edit to see if I'm understanding this correctly?